# PayPal Sandbox IPN doesn't hit notification action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal-ipn

It's my first post on StackOverflow, so please be forgiving for any mistakes.
So I've got problem with PayPal payment. I've got this:

```
this.cmd = "_xclick";
this.business = "test@test.pl";
this.cancel_return = "http://www.sever.com/PayPal/CancelFromPayPal";
this.@return = "http://www.sever.com/PayPal/ReturnFromPayPal";
if (useSandbox)
{
    this.action_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
else
{
    this.action_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
this.notify_url = "http://www.yeslogo3.pl/PayPal/NotificationFromPayPal";
this.currency_code = "USD";
```

View that sends data to PayPal:

```
<form action="@Model.action_url" id="PayPalForm" method="get">
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cmd)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.business)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.no_shipping)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.currency_code)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.amount)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.item_name)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.item_number)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.@return)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cancel_return)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.notify_url)
@*<input name="lc" type="hidden" value="@Session["Lang"]" />*@
<input name="lc" type="hidden" value="pl" />
<input name="charset" type="hidden" value="utf-8" />
<input name="bn" type="hidden" value="Test_PayPal" />

<input type="submit" value="@Frontpage.connection_to_paypal" class="paypal-redirect-button"/>
```

Action that should catch notification from PayPal:

```
private PayPalOrderManager mPayPalOrder;
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NotifyFromPayPal(FormCollection collection){
if (collection["txn_id"] != null || collection["txn_type"] != null)
{
    try
    {
        PayPalOrder model = new PayPalOrder(collection);

        UserManager mUser = new UserManager();
        var idUser = WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
        DAL.User userObj = mUser.GetItem(idUser);
        model.IdUser = idUser;
        model.UserName = userObj.Name;
        model.UserSurname = userObj.Surname;
        model.UserEmail = userObj.Email;

        mPayPalOrder.SaveItem(model);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.SaveMessage("ERROR: " + e.Message);
    }

    var queryString = "?cmd=_notify-validate";
    var transactionId = collection["txn_id"];

    foreach (var key in collection.AllKeys)
    {
        queryString = queryString + "&" + key + "=" + collection[key];
    }

    queryString = queryString + "&return=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["return"];
    queryString = queryString + "&cancel_return=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cancel_return"];
    queryString = queryString + "&notify_url=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["notify_url"];
    queryString = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" + queryString;

    // convert string to stream
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(queryString);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

    HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(queryString);
    objRequest.Method = "POST";
    objRequest.Host = "www.sandbox.paypal.com";
    objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    objRequest.ContentLength = queryString.Length;

    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            myWriter.Write(queryString);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.SaveMessage("ERROR: " + e.Message);
    }

    HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
    string result;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    var obj = mPayPalOrder.GetItemByTxn(transactionId);
    if (obj != null)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && result.ToLower().Contains("verified"))
        {
            obj.IsVerified = true;
            obj.IsInvalid = false;
        }
        else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && result.ToLower().Contains("invalid"))
        {
            obj.IsVerified = false;
            obj.IsInvalid = true;
        }
        mPayPalOrder.UpdateItem(obj);
    }
}
return View();
}
```

And I do this: send data to PayPal, login, pay and return to my website. Everything seems to be OK, but I cannot get notification from PayPal to my NotifyFromPayPal action.

In Global.asax I have this, to catch any Request:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//  check language from session and change in app

ErrorMessageManager mMessage = new ErrorMessageManager();
var model = new ErrorMessage() { CreateDate = DateTime.Now, Value = string.Concat(HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod, ": ", HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.ToString(), " | ", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url != null ? HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString() : null, " | ", HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer != null ? HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() : null) };
mMessage.SaveItem(model);
}
```

And only in Global.asax I get notification, which looks like that (POST method):

```
mc_gross=22.00
protection_eligibility=Eligible
address_status=confirmed
payer_id=N6ETD2YAA5JPA
tax=0.00
address_street=1+Main+St
payment_date=03%3a32%3a12+Mar+12%2c+2014+PDT
payment_status=Completed
charset=utf-8
address_zip=95131
first_name=Buyername
mc_fee=1.21
address_country_code=US
address_name=Buyername+Buyerlast
notify_version=3.7
custom=
payer_status=verified
business=business@test.com
address_country=United+States
address_city=San+Jose
quantity=1
payer_email=payer@test.com
verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AEf0DwvUf4fI7nbW3f1rBPjnAHIN
txn_id=6D698718VH002880D
payment_type=instant
last_name=Buyerlast
address_state=CA
receiver_email=business@test.com
payment_fee=
receiver_id=PHZETPFBE9L6Y
txn_type=web_accept
item_name=1+Clase
mc_currency=EUR
item_number=2
residence_country=US
test_ipn=1
handling_amount=0.00
transaction_subject=
payment_gross=
shipping=0.00
merchant_return_link=click+here
auth=ALW91T5gsNdysChMUJbReaBt6B9JSdLf8H23QNAVQo.gt8n1PxLsVRp2NxCzk8GCgtqYEkN2TBnK8YFfkqInD0w
```

but I don't get notification to my NotifyFromPayPal action.

When I change return url to the same address as notify_url, I get notification to my NotifyFromPayPal action and it looks like that (POST method):

```
mc_gross=22.00
protection_eligibility=Eligible
address_status=confirmed
payer_id=N6ETD2YAA5JPA
tax=0.00
address_street=1+Main+St
payment_date=04%3a41%3a28+Mar+12%2c+2014+PDT
payment_status=Completed
charset=utf-8
address_zip=95131
first_name=Buyername
mc_fee=1.21
address_country_code=US
address_name=Buyername+Buyerlast
notify_version=3.7
custom=
payer_status=verified
business=business@test.com
address_country=United+States
address_city=San+Jose
quantity=1
payer_email=payer@test.com
verify_sign=AC.iXtzEn2B9NKspM0vGmfEBKjMGA5dBoy191x9MQqW6wpdC8REWB5rU
txn_id=7R911625SC8544136
payment_type=instant
last_name=Buyerlast
address_state=CA
receiver_email=business@test.com
payment_fee=
receiver_id=PHZETPFBE9L6Y
txn_type=web_accept
item_name=1+Clase
mc_currency=EUR
item_number=2
residence_country=US
test_ipn=1
handling_amount=0.00
transaction_subject=
payment_gross=
shipping=0.00
merchant_return_link=click+here
auth=AWhbtwZJxW-WPxwhHnSzbpM4kNJ3Z9pcioRoH470uYwcwpnoQ0vDxEjs8FJu9558qBPJ-VhfgKKpSIkYsKaT5ow
```

... and when I send it back to PayPal to validate, it's always INVALID.
Does anyone has any suggestion, how to make it work?
I've spent too much time on this and I need help.